# ServiceNow - How to use SOAP to download reports

Tags: python, soap, servicenow

I need to automate download of reports from `serviceNow`.

I've been able to automate it using `python` and `selenium` and `win32com` by following method.
`https://test.service-now.com/sys_report_template.do?CSV&jvar_report_id=92a....7aa`

And using `selenium` to access `serviceNow` as well as modify `firefox` default download option to dump the file to a folder on `windows` machine.

However, Since all of this may be ported to a `linux` server , we would like to port it to `SOAP` or `CURL`.

I came across `serviceNow` libraries for `python` [here](https://github.com/locaweb/python-servicenow).

I tried it out and following code is working if I set login , password and instance-name as listed at the site using following from `ServiceNow.py`

```
class Change(Base):
    __table__ = 'change_request.do'
```

and following within clientside script as listed on [site](https://github.com/locaweb/python-servicenow).

```
# Fetch changes updated on the last 5 minutes
changes = chg.last_updated(minutes=5)
#print changes client side script.

for eachline in changes:
    print eachline
```

However, When I replace URL with `sys_report_template.do`, I am getting error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\SOAPpy\Parser.py", line 1080, in _parseSOAP
    parser.parse(inpsrc)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\xml\sax\xmlreader.py", line 125, in parse
    self.close()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py", line 220, in close
    self.feed("", isFinal = 1)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py", line 214, in feed
    self._err_handler.fatalError(exc)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\xml\sax\handler.py", line 38, in fatalError
    raise exception
SAXParseException: <unknown>:1:0: no element found
```

Here is relevent code

```
from servicenow import ServiceNow
from servicenow import Connection
from servicenow.drivers import SOAP

# For SOAP connection
conn = SOAP.Auth(username='abc', password='def', instance='test')

rpt  = ServiceNow.Base(conn)
rpt.__table__ = "sys_report_template.do?CSV"

#jvar_report_id replaced with .... to protect confidentiality
report = rpt.fetch_one({'jvar_report_id': '92a6760a......aas'})

for eachline in report:
    print eachline
```

So, my question is , what can be done to make this work? 
I looked on web for resources and help, but didn't find any.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research I was able to use following method to get report in `csv` format from `servicenow`. I thought I will post over here in case anyone else runs into similar issue.

```
import requests
import json

# Set the request parameters
url= 'https://myinstance.service-now.com/sys_report_template.do?CSV&jvar_report_id=929xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0c755'
user = 'my_username'
pwd = 'my_password'

# Set proper headers
headers = {"Accept":"application/json"}

# Do the HTTP request
response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers )
response.raise_for_status()
print response.text
```

`response.text` now has report in `csv` format.
I need to next figure out, how to parse the `response` object to extract `csv` data in correct format.
Once done, I will post over here. But for now this answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and its working as expected.
`import requests
import json

url= 'https://myinstance.service-now.com/sys_report_template.do?CSV&jvar_report_id=929xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0c755'
user = 'my_username'
pwd = 'my_password'

response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers )

file_name = "abc.csv"

with open(file_name, 'wb') as out_file:
    out_file.write(response.content)
del response`